# MS Access 2013: Joining tables multiple times

Tags: ms-access

*I am totally new to MS Access, so please be kind if my requests might look nonsense.*
I have a database with two tables: `tblHerbs` and `tblSeasons`.
Two fields in tblHerbs refer to tblSeasons and I don't know how to **set the relation between these two tables**, besides **building a simple query** that allows me to select everything from tblHerbs (and show it on a Report).

[image]

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  alias

```
select t.Season1, s1.name, t.Season2, s2.name
from  ((tblHerbs t
inner join tblSeasons s1 on s1.name= t.Season1 )
inner join tblSeasons s2 on s2.name= t.Season2)
```

Comment: Thank you @scaisEdge for the quick reply.
BTW what do `col`, `col1` and `col2` refer to? The one field from tblSeasons that I need to be referred to twice on tblHerbs is labeled `name`

Comment: name is the columnName  i table tblHerbs ?  .. and which are the related columns name in table tblSeasons ??

Comment: It's two columns in tblHerbs (labelled Season1 and Season2) that each refer to the same column in tbsSeasons labelled (name)

Comment: answer  updated ..  hope is what ypu are looking for

Comment: Well to be honest I am actually looking for a way to set the relationships (lines) between these two tables. 

In the image attached in the main post I should theoretically draw an arrow, left-to-right, from tblSeasons.name to tblHerbs.season1 and at the same time from tblSeasons.name to tblHerbs.season2. If I do that, Access duplicates tblSeasons into tblSeason1 and creates two one-to-many relations, but then when I run the query to look at the whole dataset, tblHerbs.Season1 is ok but tblHerbs.Season2 is duplicated with the value from tblHerbs.Season1.
This is my issue.

Comment: i have updated .  the query adding in select  the 4 columns involved  .hope is more clear

Comment: Yes, thank you, now I got it 100%. Many thanks for the patience. Bless

Comment: @frons79 I am very pleased  .. you are welcome